# How to block unwanted bot in Apache 2.4?

Tags: htaccess, apache

These rules work good in my .htaccess:

```
#https://workinnet.ru/de/wie-man-amazonbot-blockiert/#German language#
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Amazonbot" blocked_bot
<Limit GET POST HEAD>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from env=blocked_bot
</Limit>
```

I tried this for use on Apache 4.4:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Amazonbot" blocked_bot
<Limit GET POST HEAD>
    <RequireAll>
        Require all granted
        Require not env blocked_bot
    </RequireAll>
</Limit>
```

But this does not work. What is wrong?

Comment: In itself, the 2nd config looks OK, however, where exactly have you put this config and what other directives do you have? (You must not _mix_ old (Apache 2.2) style `Order`, `Allow`, `Deny` directives with the newer Apache 2.4 `Require` directive.)

Comment: This config is put rather to the end of .htaccess. I have a lot of other directives. The only old directive is the upper shown, all other are "require" instead of "allow/deny". But this old directive works good. But the 2.4. updated version does not work. It is "permeable".

Comment: Your  <RequireAll> directive works like an AND operator. Both of the next 2 conditions must be true for it to work. You can safely remove the line that says "Require all granted" and it should work

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran No you can't. A _negated_ `Require` directive is never considered "true". Access must be granted _somewhere_. From [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require), "when the Require directive is negated it can only fail or return a neutral result, and therefore may never independently authorize a request.". So, if you _only_ have a (negated) `Require not ...` directive then it won't actually do anything.

Comment: Please update your question with your complete `.htaccess` file with these directives in place. And what specific Apache version are you on? The most likely cause is that you have a conflict with other authorizing directives outside of this code block. Since the default container is `<RequireAny>`, any authorizing directives elsewhere in the file that are not "contained" will take priority and authorize access. (Please also clarify that you are not on a LiteSpeed server masquerading as Apache - which could also cause these directives to be ineffective).

Comment: I think my huge .htaccess (almost 800 lines) would be an imposition for everyone here, so I'll leave it out.
My webspace provider says I have: Apache 2.4.51
I don't have a <RequireAny> in the .htacess

Far above in the .htaccess I have "RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}" to lock out some very stubborn spammers or spambots,
further down I have "Require not IP",
below I have rules from "7G" from perishablepress.com
It is said that you should write the most important rules high up in the .htaccess.

Comment: The Amazon bot in particular can only be locked out as shown.
It works, the mix of "Require" and "Deny" is just a flaw that bothers me.

By the way: does anyone know a good .htaccess with significantly fewer than 800 lines?

Comment: "I think my huge .htaccess (almost 800 lines) would be an imposition for everyone here" - Maybe, but that wouldn't necessarily take as much time to wade through as you might think. "I don't have a `<RequireAny>` in the .htacess" - Although, as I mentioned, "RequireAny" is the implied _default_, when no "RequireXXXX" container is explicitly used. So, if you have no `<RequireAny>` container then the whole file is effectively one big `<RequireAny>` container (this could be the problem)! The new Apache 2.4 authorisation directives are not a drop in replacement for the old, they work differently.

Comment: "It is said that you should write the most important rules high up in the .htaccess." - Well, the most _specific_ rules need to be first, otherwise later rules might not be processed at all (like any computer script). However, different modules are processed independently, so the order between modules is not necessarily important, except for logical/readability.

Comment: "the mix of "Require" and "Deny" is just a flaw that bothers me" - The `Deny` directive (now part of mod_access_compat in Apache 2.4 - for backwards compatibility only) is formerly deprecated so could potentially be removed altogether in future versions of Apache (although I don't see that happening any time soon). Although mod_access_compat is now an optional extension and is not present on all Apache 2.4 servers.

Comment: "I think my huge .htaccess (almost 800 lines) would be an imposition for everyone here- Maybe, but that wouldn't necessarily take as much time to wade through as you might think."

stackexchange does not allow such large text, an does not allow some phrases.
So I uploaded the htaccess-file here:
netzjahre.com/test/htastexchange.txt

Comment: @MrWhite, thx for your hints.

Comment: @josefus I think I have an idea what the problem might be (having had a quick look at your `.htacccess` file)... sorry, not time at the moment, I'll post back tomorrow...

Comment: @MrWhite, don't hurry - "is just a flaw that bothers me".

Comment: After some times, I tried the new "require" again instead of the "allow/deny". And now it works, but I don't know why.
I think the problem is solved.